# How to obtain email of the logged in user in powershell

Tags: powershell, ldap, powershell-2.0

Using Vbscript , we are getting current user email id. It is as simple as with following lines.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objUser, objADSysInfo

Set objADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objADSysInfo.UserName)
WScript.Echo objUser.Mail
```

How to achieve the same using powershell?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
PS> $searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$env:USERNAME)"
PS> $searcher.FindOne().Properties.mail
```

Comment: I don't know how to explain my happiness in words. Really thanks buddy. I just went for coffee and answer is here. Stackoverflow rocks and levy also Rocks :)

Comment: Anyone know how to do this for an Azure AD joined computer (Office 265)?

Comment: Note: This is case sensitive; i.e. `.Mail` does not work, `.mail` does.

Answer (score 23):

I'd be concerned that the given answer doesn't use the fully qualified name. Granted that won't be a problem in most cases, but the method I'm using is as follows:

```
([adsi]"LDAP://$(whoami /fqdn)").mail
```