# How do you obtain the Active Directory email address of the current logged in user in PowerShell Core?

Tags: .net-core, powershell-core

I've seen other questions/answers here that show how to do this in Windows PowerShell, and they work in Windows PowerShell, but not in PowerShell 6+, i.e., PowerShell Core, which is built on top of .NET Core.

How do I get the Active Directory email address of the domain-joined current user in PowerShell Core?

If they are not AD-domain joined, it doesn't matter what it does (throws an error, returns an empty string, whatever).

Thanks!

I've looked into the example here: [How to obtain email of the logged in user in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666627/how-to-obtain-email-of-the-logged-in-user-in-powershell), but the "`[adsi]`" types are not available.

I've considered `"$env:username@$env:userdnsdomain"`, but that gives incorrect results.

Thanks!

Note: this is in Windows (Windows 10, specifically). I need the user's email address in order to generate an auth token with ADAL. It can do it without the user's email address in .NET, but not in .NET Core.

For example, I've got a user whose login is `m8345`. His email address could be "`mike@somedomain.com`" or "`mike@otherdomain.com`" or "`mike@ntdev.somedomain.com`" or "`mike.smith@somedomain.com`", etc., i.e., there's not necessarily any correlation between the logon name (i.e., "%username%") and the email address... yet .NET can resolve it, but .NET core cannot.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your environment. Since your question is tagged `powershell-core` I'm assuming that you're not running Windows, so what is your OS, and where are the users' email addresses stored?

Comment: Ansgar---I edited the question. As for "where are the users' email addresses stored?", if I knew that, then I wouldn't need to ask, i.e., that is the crux of my question.

Comment: what if it is a local account, and the user does not have an email address on their account?

Comment: Meghan: if it's a local account, then failing or returning an empty string is acceptable. Basically, I don't need this for those cases, so any behavior in those cases is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much tribulation, I figured it out:

```
([ADSI]"LDAP://<SID=$([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User.Value)>").UserPrincipalName
```

Comment: That does not provide any email address on my system. I think you need to limit the scope of your question to something, such as users in a domain or whatnot. My computer is a personal computer. It's Windows 10, but that expression produces nothing.

Comment: I updated the question to specify what I'm looking for---only for AD domain users, on a domain-joined machine.

Comment: You are retrieving the User Principal Name field here, which is not the same as the 'Email Address' field in Active Directory. Try '.mail' instead.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method using [ADSystemInfo COM object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsadsysteminfo) to retrieve the user's DistinguishedName, then retrieving the 'mail' property:

```
([ADSI]"LDAP://$([System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("UserName", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, (New-Object -ComObject "ADSystemInfo"), $null))").mail
```